# How can I add a new Vertex only if it is possible to add an Edge too?

Tags: tinkerpop3, amazon-neptune, tinkergraph

I need to add a new Vertex with an Edge. 
My code is something like:

```
g.V().addV("Vertex").addE("MyEdge").to(V().has("OtherVertex", "name", "test"))
```

If `V().has("OtherVertex", "name", "test")` return a Vertex, everything works fine. My problem is if the `OtherVertex` doesn't exist, Gremlin add the new Vertex without edges. I would like to add the new Vertex only if I can create the Edge.
I am using Gremlin-server for developing. My guess is, I could try to use `Transactions`, but I am not sure if AWS Neptune support it now.

Any suggestion?
Thanks.

---

I think, avoiding transactions, I realize that I can select `OtherVertex` first. If it doesn't exist, the query will not create a new Vertex:

```
g.V().has("OtherVertex", "name", "test").as('t').addV("Vertex").as('v').addE("MyEdge").from('v').to('t')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote, this is the correct approach:

```
g.V().has("OtherVertex", "name", "test").as('t').
  addV("Vertex").as('v').addE("MyEdge").from('v').to('t')
```

I would just add something in relation to your initial attempt that showed:

```
g.V().addV("Vertex")
```

I think you simply meant to start with:

```
g.addV("Vertex")
```

If you go with the former you create some unintended problems:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> g.V().addV('person')
gremlin> g.V().addV('person')
gremlin> g
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
```

Note that nothing gets added for an empty graph. That is because `V()` returns no vertices and therefore there is nothing in the pipeline to trigger `addV()` with. Let's assume you have some data though:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().addV('person')
==>v[13]
==>v[14]
==>v[15]
==>v[16]
==>v[17]
==>v[18]
gremlin> g.V().addV('person')
==>v[19]
==>v[20]
==>v[21]
==>v[22]
==>v[23]
==>v[24]
==>v[25]
==>v[26]
==>v[27]
==>v[28]
==>v[29]
==>v[30]
```

Now, there's an even worse problem in that we're adding one vertex for every existing vertex as `V()` now returns all the vertices in the graph on each execution.

As a final note, please see this [Gremlin Recipe](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#element-existence) for ways to do get-or-create type operations as it's related to this conditional sort of mutation that you're doing now.